# VB.Net: Is there any way to rename the points in a chart to type "string" instead of type "double"?

Tags: vb.net, charts, series

The chart I am creating will populate with grades that a student has been given for different pieces of work.
The details aren't really important, but basically here's the code I'm using:

```
If .Grade.ToString.ToUpper = "U" Then
                    ctGrade.Series("Series1").Points.Add(0)
                ElseIf .Grade.ToString.ToUpper = "E" Then
                    ctGrade.Series("Series1").Points.Add(1)
                ElseIf .Grade.ToString.ToUpper = "D" Then
                    ctGrade.Series("Series1").Points.Add(2)
                ElseIf .Grade.ToString.ToUpper = "C" Then
                    ctGrade.Series("Series1").Points.Add(3)
                ElseIf .Grade.ToString.ToUpper = "B" Then
                    ctGrade.Series("Series1").Points.Add(4)
                ElseIf .Grade.ToString.ToUpper = "A" Then
                    ctGrade.Series("Series1").Points.Add(5)
                End If
```

The chart is called "ctGrade". Now, the chart is populating fine, for example, if a student has two grade B's and a grade E, then the chart will come up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i78ur.jpg

However i want the numbers along the Y axis (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to be called the letter of the grade instead, ie, (E, D, C, B, A,). If I try changing ".Add(1)" to ".Add("E")" then I just get an error saying that I cannot convert from type string to type double.

Does anyone know how to change the 1,2,3,4,5 from the Y axis to be letters instead?

Comment: What chart library are you using?

Comment: I just dragged in the standard chart from the data section in the toolbox